# Function invocation failed: Error: define cannot be used indirect while using netlify

Tags: express, webpack, netlify

I am trying do deploy express server with help of netlify.
these are my scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/netlify-lambda serve src",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/.bin/netlify-lambda build src"
  },
```

I am able to run the server with `npm run build` and server is running but when i hit any api i get error saying `Function invocation failed: Error: define cannot be used indirect`

After searching I got solution to add

```
module: {
    noParse: /node_modules\/json-schema\/lib\/validate\.js/
}
```

but i dont know where to add this